# Windows fails to boot every even time

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

On one of my computers Windows 10 x64 with recent updates installed shows the following behaviour.

1. On boot it says about start up problems and brings me to the repair screen on the blue background.
2. I choose, `Start Windows 10` and then it asks for language to use.
3. When I choose the language, Windows restarts the computer and after that starts as expected.

In case during this restart I turn the computer off, next time it will start without any issues.
At the same time, if I start Windows and then leave it in normal way (Start menu->Power->Shut down), the problem with boot will happen again.

So, formally I have the problem on every start, but really it is “every even time”, since I have a reboot by Windows in the middle.

I don’t want to reinstall Windows, since I have lots of programs, keys, passwords, etc. installed on the PC, so reinstallation could take significant time.

Are there any ideas how to fix or at least understand the root cause of this?

I checked the disk with `chkdsk`, it is just fine. And when Windows starts it works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

> On boot it says about start up problems and brings me to the repair
> screen on the blue background.

In all cases I have seen with this message, either:
(1) The operating system has been seriously damaged.  OR
(2) There is a hardware (often main disk) error.

> I don’t want to reinstall Windows,

I understand, but this is the likely option.  If Windows could have repaired the problem, it would have done a Reset keeping apps and data.

You need to recover your data.  If you can do this at a time when it starts, do that. You can boot with a bootable USB Key if things get worse.

Then get the manufacturer's hardware diagnostics on bootable USB key and test all hardware, particularly the main disk.

If the hardware is OK, then reinstall Windows.

If you can get it to start, you can try Reset from the recovery menu. That may work, but the odds are against it.

---

Note:  Remember that Windows 10 is fast approaching End of Life. If there is any kind of hardware error, now may be the time to upgrade to Windows 11.

Comment: I agree that there is likely a problem with the hard disk, especially if it's a 'spinning platter' disk rather than a SSD. I have seen similar issues in the past when the drive bearings are going and the disk takes longer to 'spin up' to normal speed; once the drive is spinning at normal speed, the boot sequence would proceed normally, and I could "restart" with no problems - but a "shutdown", which would stop the drive spin, would cause the problem to exhibit on startup.

Comment: No issues with Windows (except boot) and with disk. I have checked the disk with chkdsk with surface test. I will check the hardware overnight. So, I don't think this is related to disk. Updated the question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, actually I have SSD there and I checked it with chkdsk with the "surface" test. No issues.

Comment: If there are no hardware errors then you have (as I mentioned) OS damage and you still need to reinstall windows / upgrade to Windows 11.

Comment: If you can get the computer started properly, you can try a Windows Reset from the Recovery Menu (noted in my answer) but the odds do not favor this,